# AngularJS export controller method to the DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in AngularJS, and I found it is awesome.

However since I used to use jQuery, and I always to use the [anonymous self executing function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368583/why-are-self-executing-anonymous-functions-used-in-javascript-module-pattern) to keep my private variables and method inaccessible, only export the required to the DOM(the global `window` object).

And when I following the [AngularJS tutorials](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) step by step, I found that all my controller method are exported to the DOM, I wonder if this is reasonable or be avoided?

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS only makes the `$scope` elements available on the DOM. That too is controller using either interpolation or expressions,

If you take the module approach to creating your controllers and define you properties and methods correctly inside you controllers. They cannot be access inside the DOM without the help of the framework.

In this case the controller should be defined as

```
angular.module('MyModule')
   .controller('MyCtrl',function(['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.myVar=1;
        $scope.myFunction=function() {}
        var myPrivatevar=2;
        var myPrivateFunction=function() {}
}]));
```

In your HTML only the `myVar` and `myFunction` would be exposed for direct interpolation or expression binding anything else has been encapsulated away from the DOM.