# Are there any benefits to writing a jquery onload function like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a piece of code that a colleague of mine uses whenever he writes javascript. Are there any benefits from a 'no conflict with other libraries' point of view to doing it this way?

```
jQuery((function($) {
    return function () {

        // code here

    };
}(jQuery)));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a combination of the [self-executing anonymous function pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368583/why-are-self-executing-anonymous-functions-used-in-javascript-module-pattern)

```
(function(window, document, $, undefined){
  ...
}(window, document, jQuery));
```

and the jQuery shorthand for `document.ready`:

```
jQuery(function($){
 ...
});
```

To get all the advantages you could do:

```
jQuery(
  (function(window, document, $, undefined) {
     ...
  }(window, document, jQuery);
));
```

The benefits of this are:

- Privateness of variables in closure established by the anonymous function
- Minor performance gains by making globals available as local variables in the closure
- Ensures `typeof(undefined) === 'undefined'`
- Independence of `$` being tampered with by other scripts
- Running this closure only when `domready` has fired
- Benefits code compression tools by allowing globals to be referenced with shortened variable names. Think `window` > `w`

Comment: How does what OP posted handle items 2 and 3 in your list?

Comment: Actually yeah, I have marked this as correct answer but I am a bit baffled now you've mentioned it especially by number 3 in the list.

Comment: What I actually meant was the **possibility** to take advantage of 2 and 3 by passing additional arguments into the self-executing function. Updating the answer body accordingly.

Comment: Ah, so in the case of undefined. It's definitely not been tampered with. Makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it won't conflict with other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it'l allow you to continue to use `$` when another library overwrites it. However, your sample is a bit over-complicated; it can be simplified to:

```
jQuery(function($){
    // code here
});
```

or

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // code here
});
```

without losing any of the benefits.

Comment: But is $ actually passed in to the function in these examples?

Comment: `$` is whatever the argument to the function is--`$` is the reference *inside* the function. The function is being *called* with `jQuery`. *Inside* the function, `$` will be `jQuery` in this case.

Comment: I see, so there definitely isn't a single benefit to the original code over the first example. The original is just a more academic example of how closures work.

Answer (score 0):

He is using jQuery's `$.noConflict()` mode which frees up the $ for other libraries just as jQuery does, more info [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Usually you would not need to do this unless you are using an additional library that is conflicting with jQuery. It can also be used to load 2 different version of jQuery.

Comment: I don't see where he's actually using Jquery's `$.noConflict()` method. It is using a similar technique. What the OP's code is doing is setting a scope so that all the code inside the returned function can use the `$` keyword for Jquery code and all the code on the outside can use the `$` keyword for anything else.

Comment: @FillipPeyton - Good call. How we used to do it before switching to jQuery's $.noConflict() method.

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually an "onload" function, but an "onready" function.

But if you mean whether to use jQuery instead of $, the benefit is definitely to prevent conflicts.

EDIT:

I think you may have mistyped the code. What you want to have is

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    // code here
  });
})(jQuery);
```

This creates an anonymous function where $ is passed in as an argument so that any other global $ does not conflict. It then calls the anonymous function passing in jQuery as the $ parameter.

Comment: The code isn't mistyped. The immediate function executes and returns another function, which is then the function which is passed to the jQuery function as an argument.

Comment: jQuery is then available within the closure as $ (or jQuery).

Comment: Ahha, I see. So two ways to skin the cat then.