# Clicks being missed on pages using userscript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to click every link with a `.vbseo_like_link` class. Therefore I am using the following code:

```
jQ('.vbseo_like_link').each(function(){
    if((jQ(this).parent().parent().parent().css("opacity") > 0.5) && (jQ(this).children().hasClass('hwz-unlike-button') == false))
        this.click();
});
```

*(Using `jQ` instead of `$` to avoid jquery conflicts with webpage itself.)*

The if statement is merely a check to make sure that the button is not already pressed so you can ignore that. The problem is that not all of the buttons are being pressed before the next aspect of the code is run, which presses the next page button:

```
var nextButton = jQ('#content ul a:contains("Next ›")');
if(nextButton.length > 0) {
    nextButton[0].click();
}
```

For some reason the nextpage is getting hit before it is finished the previous clicking. Could this be due to the fact that the page is not all the way loaded? Here is my full code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @namespace       likeButton
// @name            Hit that like button! 
// @description     Hit that like button!
// @author          Justin (Fogest)
// @match           http://forums.hardwarezone.com.sg/*
// @run-at document-end
// ==/UserScript==

// a function that loads jQuery and calls a callback function when jQuery has finished loading
function addJQuery(callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("src", "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js");
  script.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent = "window.jQ=jQuery.noConflict(true);(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, false);
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

// the guts of this userscript
function main() {
    jQ('.vbseo_like_link').each(function(){
        if((jQ(this).parent().parent().parent().css("opacity") > 0.5) && (jQ(this).children().hasClass('hwz-unlike-button') == false))
            this.click();
    });
    var nextButton = jQ('#content ul a:contains("Next ›")');
    if(nextButton.length > 0) {
        nextButton[0].click();
    }
}

document.addEventListener('load', addJQuery(main));
```

Comment: Just a side note: You could use the [self-executing anonymous function pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368583/why-are-self-executing-anonymous-functions-used-in-javascript-module-pattern) to prevent the jQuery conflict.

Comment: @marionebl I don't quite get how to implement that.

Comment: lol, you want to click all the like links by script? shame...

Comment: @ariel yes? What is the problem here? I am actually not making this for myself, but for a friend. It is a nice learning experience of how to use Javascript/jQuery to interact with a page via a userscript.

Comment: I agree with @Fogest, whats is the issue with clicking links by script?